# How to deactivate compressing in grunt less?

Tags: css, gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less

The [`grunt-contrib-less`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less) package provides the option [`compress`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/#compress), that should allow managing uglifying/minifying/compression of the destination CSS file. It is a `boolean` with the default value `false`.

For any reason it woesn't work for me -- whatever I set the parameter to, the output CSS file is compressed. Ho to get it working correctly?

---

**`Gruntfile.js`**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          paths: ["public/css"],
          compress: false
        },
        files: {
          "public/css/style.css": "public/css/style.less"
        }
      },
      production: {
        options: {
          paths: ["public/css"],
          compress: false,
          plugins: [
            new (require('less-plugin-autoprefix'))({browsers: ["last 2 versions"]}),
            new (require('less-plugin-clean-css'))([])
          ],
          modifyVars: {
          }
        },
        files: {
          "public/css/style.css": "public/css/style.less"
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "less" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);

};
```

**CLI**

```
$ grunt --version
grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.5
$ grunt
Running "less:development" (less) task
File public/css/style.css created

Running "less:production" (less) task
File public/css/style.css created

Done, without errors.
```

Comment: You need to post your solution as a separate answer (otherwise it's not that evident the problem is solved).

Answer (score 1):

It was my bad... The CSS files have been compressed because of the usage of the `less-plugin-clean-css`. After I've removed it, the compressing can be managed again by the `compress` parameter.